# Splitting string by using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, date

I have a long string in format:

```
"DD.MM.YYYY comments for this date ; DD.MM.YYYY comments for another date ; etc".
```

I want to split the string for array (date + description). I tried to split by using this pattern, but it matches the entire string instead of splitting.

```
(\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4})[^(\1)]*
```

I can't split by `;` divider, because text can possibly include it.

Comment: Java. Sorry, I didn't point it.

Comment: Ok then you should include some sample inputs and your expected outputs.

Comment: The problem will probably be the ambiguity of `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4})\D*
```

This will match a date followed by any non-digit character.

If the description can contain digits, then try:

```
((\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4}).*?(; (?=\d))|(\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4}).*$)
```

This will match a date followed by anything until meeting a semi-colon followed by a space and a digit or a date followed by anything until the end of the string.

If you want to use the date as a divider (instead of the semi-colon followed by a space and a digit), then try this:

```
((\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4}).*?((?=(\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4})))|(\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4}).*$)
```

Comment: It works fine, if there is no digits in text, otherwise there will be text loss. I want to use "dd.mm.yyyy" as a divider. I tried to use backreferences in my sample, but it did not work clear in my case.

Comment: Check my updated answer. The second one allows digits in description. I also included a version for the date as a divider.

Comment: Thanks. I checked it on 4-items string. There were 2 matches found: first 3 items and the last. I tried another string, and there is always 2 matches - the last one and others. Sorry for my perseverance, I just try to find correct solution.

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot a question mark after the asterisk in the second and third regex. Check them now.